# Submit button for a formset doesn't work when generated by ajax

Tags: javascript, python, html, ajax, django

I have a formset to update my models and I display forms from my formset based on the search query. I have an ajax keyup function to send post requests so I can generate search_results.html that I then pass to  in search.html.

Now, if I generate the forms dynamically the submit button does not work. If I ditch the search and pass the content of search_results.html to search.html directly it does work.

I have two views, SearchReportView which supposed to be the main one, and SearchReports to handle generating the report. I guess I might just merge them at this point - it doesn't solve my problem though.

Also I had this working before when I used multiple forms but I had to switch to a formset.

body of search.html

```
<div class="container">

        <div class="navbar">
            <div class="navbarItem">
                <a href="{% url 'EnbListView' %}"><img src="{% static 'back.png' %}" width="20px" height="12px" \>Back</a>
            </div>
        </div>

    <div>
        <h3>Search:</h3>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" id="search" name="search" />
                <span class="button-checkbox">
                <button id="mybutton" type="button" class="btn" data-color="primary">Recent</button>
                <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" name="reports_checkbox" checked />
                </span>
    </div>

        <div class="normalText" id="search-results"></div>

</div>
```

search_results.html

```
                    {% if reports_and_formset %}
                    <form action="/TP/auto/report/search/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ formset.management_form }}
                    {% for x, form in reports_and_formset %}

                            <button type="submit" class="button" >Submit</button>
                            {{ form.checking_user }}
                            {{ form.comment }}
                            {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                {{ hidden }}
                            {% endfor %}

                    {% endfor %}
                    </form>
                {% else %}
                    <tr> <td> <center>
                    No results found.
                    </center></td></tr>
                {% endif %}
```

views.py

```
class SearchReportView(FormView):

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # form = ReportCommentForm(initial={'comment': ''})
    # context = {'form': form}

    if 'form-TOTAL_FORMS' in request.POST:

        single_day_enb_reports = SingleDayEnbReport.objects.all()

        report_form_set = modelformset_factory(SingleDayEnbReport, form=ReportCommentForm,
                                               max_num=single_day_enb_reports.count())

        formset = report_form_set(request.POST, queryset=single_day_enb_reports)

        formset.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/TP/auto/report/search/report_search/')

# @requires_csrf_token
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'app/search.html')


class SearchReports(View):

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    single_day_enb_reports = SingleDayEnbReport.objects.all()

    report_form_set = modelformset_factory(SingleDayEnbReport, form=ReportCommentForm, max_num=single_day_enb_reports.count())
    formset = report_form_set(queryset=single_day_enb_reports)

    single_day_enb_reports_and_formset = zip(single_day_enb_reports, formset)
    # context = {'single_day_enb_reports': single_day_enb_reports, 'formset': formset}
    context = {'reports_and_formset': single_day_enb_reports_and_formset, 'formset': formset}

    return render(request, 'app/search_results.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@classmethod
def calculate_dates(self): #not important

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):

    if 'form-TOTAL_FORMS' in request.POST:

        single_day_enb_reports = SingleDayEnbReport.objects.all()

        report_form_set = modelformset_factory(SingleDayEnbReport, form=ReportCommentForm,
                                               max_num=single_day_enb_reports.count())

        formset = report_form_set(request.POST, queryset=single_day_enb_reports)

        # if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/TP/auto/report/search/report_search/')

    if 'button_state' in request.POST:
        search_text = request.POST['search_text']
        button_state = request.POST['button_state']

        if button_state == 'false':
            button_state = False
        else:
            button_state = True

        if button_state:
            now, fit_date = self.calculate_dates()
            single_day_enb_reports = SingleDayEnbReport.objects.all().filter(
                                                         Q(last_modification_date__range=[fit_date, now]) & (
                                                         Q(alarms__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(enb__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(creation_date__date__contains=search_text) |
                                                         Q(last_modification_date__date__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(comment__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(checking_user__name__contains=search_text)))
        else:
            single_day_enb_reports = SingleDayEnbReport.objects.all().filter(
                                                         Q(alarms__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(enb__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(creation_date__date__contains=search_text) |
                                                         Q(last_modification_date__date__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(comment__contains=search_text)|
                                                         Q(checking_user__name__contains=search_text))

        report_form_set = modelformset_factory(SingleDayEnbReport, form=ReportCommentForm,
                                                   max_num=single_day_enb_reports.count())
        formset = report_form_set(queryset=single_day_enb_reports)

        single_day_enb_reports_and_formset = zip(single_day_enb_reports, formset)

        context = {'reports_and_formset': single_day_enb_reports_and_formset, 'formset': formset}
        return render_to_response('app/search_results.html', context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ajax.js

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){

delay(function(){
    if($('input[name=reports_checkbox]:checked').val()) button_state = true
    else button_state = false


        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TP/auto/report/search/report_search/",
            data: {
                'button_state' : button_state,
                'search_text' : $('#search').val(),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: 'html'
        });
 }, 500 );

});
});

    function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
    //generated data is put into search-results <div>field in search.html
    $('#search-results').html(data);
}
```

Comment: Read up on ***[Event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)***

Comment: Thanks, I did. So there is no way to post the form without event handler? Is it somehow possible to get the post to generate without refering to every single field by it's id?

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking

Comment: Is it possible to use submit button without rewriting it's function in jQuery?

Comment: Use classes instead of id's when you have multiple forms. Within an event handler can traverse to current form. Really seems like you need to ask a more specific question

Comment: I guess doing the following will eventually work, thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Now I have to deal with csrf token.

 $(document).on('click','button', function(){
        $('#myForm').trigger( "submit" );
        console.log("form submitted!")  // sanity check
});

Comment: just be aware you can't duplicate id's in a page... not entirely clear what you have going on

Answer (score 0):

Please change your this line

```
$('#search').keyup(function(){
```

with

```
$(document).on('keyup','#search', function(){
```

Comment: My '  $('#search').keyup(function(){ is inside of  ' $(function () { ' . And the search works just fine, it's the formset submiting I can't figure out.